# Algortihm to sort by increasing/decreasing

Tags: algorithms

Suppose, you are given a list of $n$ tubs, $T[i]$, $i=1(1)n$. Initially, each tub contains $c[i]$ litre water. Each tub has two taps, from one (if kept open) water enters  $x$ litre/minute, and from the other (if kept open) water exits  $y$ litre/minute. One can open both taps/one tap of a tube or can close both of them. The problem is to find out an algorithm, which will make $T[i] < T[i+1]$, $i=1(1)n-1$ by suitably opening/closing/remaining as it is the tap(s) of the tubs and that would minimize the time required. Assume all regularity conditions (e.g. $x>0$ etc.).

For example, say, tub 1 initially holds $6$ litre water, incoming speed is $2$ litre/minute, outgoing speed is $1$ litre/minute. That for the tub $2$ and $3$ are: $4$, $1$, $3$; $4$, $1$, $4$, respectively. The solution is $2$ minutes, as given below:

> Open exit tap of tub 1 ($2$ minutes)
>
> Open enter tap of tub 2 ($1$ minute)
>
> Open enter tab of tub 3 ($2$ minutes)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do taps have to be opened for integer numbers of minutes?

Comment: @BrianTung Yes. Everything is a natural number.

Comment: What kind of algorithm are you looking for? You have a well-defined, discrete state space with at most $3^n$ different transitions that can occur from any state to the next. Starting from an initial state, and given the (finite) set of possible "moves", various search algorithms can find an optimal path to a state that satisfies the solution criterion. Breadth-first search might be an OK choice, since you want the earliest time. But the problem grows exponentially, so you might want to do branch-and-bound or some even better optimization.